# How to convert a mutable pointer into a struct with a ref inside?

Tags: rust

How to simplify this code (please, don't ask what it's for):

```
pub fn f<'a>(p: *mut Option<u64>) -> Option<&'a mut u64> {
    match unsafe { &mut *(p.add(5)) } {
        Some(p) => Some(p),
        None => None,
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to turn a pointer to an `Option` into an `Option` with a reference inside. It works perfectly this way, however there is an obvious redundancy. I already have `Option`, making a new one is a redundant step. Can I just convert a pointer into a struct?

Comment: Again you put the `unsafe` boundary at the wrong spot, since one can pick an arbitrary lifetime this function **must not** be available to safe code but made a `pub unsafe fn` instead, the caller *has to* uphold the condition that the pointer is valid for `'a` and that the space `5` `u64` over is a valid pointer, too. As is this function is unsound because it can be used to cause UB in safe code.

Comment: @yegor256, you should accept @drewtato's answer instead of mine, this should be an `unsafe fn` instead of an `unsafe` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, this function is unsafe. It cannot be called if there is another reference to `p` + 5, or if it is not an initialized or valid `Option<u64>`, among other things.

You can simply dereference the value and then call [`as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut) on it.

```rs
pub unsafe fn f<'a>(p: *mut Option<u64>) -> Option<&'a mut u64> {
    (*p.add(5)).as_mut()
}
```